# Csv mapper quotes strings in csv

Tags: csv, jackson, export-to-csv

I am saving data in a CSV file for every row but it seems that some strings that are getting saved, get quoted and other do not get quoted for example the output is

REEasdasdEEE;CUSTOMER_IDENTIFICATION;"Table Test does not exist";"12";"10"

Here is the configuration I use for CSV mapper

````
    final CsvMapper csvMapper = new CsvMapper();
        csvMapper.enable(JsonGenerator.Feature.IGNORE_UNKNOWN);
        csvMapper.enable(JsonGenerator.Feature.WRITE_NUMBERS_AS_STRINGS);
and 

  csvSchema.schemaFor(clazz).withColumnSeparator(';')
                .withLineSeparator("\r\n");
    ```
How can I disable this quoting with " when saving into the file?

I expect no quoting to be added in the output csv file for the columns .
I am using jackson-data-format-csv-2.12.3
````

Comment: resolved you need to youse withoutQuoteChar on the object